# Jenkins Build log on slave

Tags: jenkins

I am using a Master/Slave setup for doing builds. This works fine, however I have a script that runs through the build log and pulls out the count of lines compiled (these are output in the log by the compiler).

When this runs on the Master, the build log can be found, now it runs on the Slave, then the build log is not found.

This maybe a simple answer, but I can't see an answer for it here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you trying to do this?  Are you using a Jenkins plug-in?  Which one?

Comment: I am running a Powershell script over the log file. Obviously the log file is located on the master, so it it fails.

Comment: I have a similar situation with a Master build machine and several slave build machines.  I am able to access artifact files on any machine.  What is preventing you from finding the build log?  And, from where are you trying to access it?

Comment: The Build artifacts are on the Slave, I can get to all of these. The problem is the build log itself, which in on the Master (unless I am totally confused).

Comment: Maybe it's a matter of semantics.  When you say "build log" are you referring to the output form the compiler?

Comment: Yes - the compiler output and the log of what is happening in Jenkins (on the Master this is located in the '..\builds\$env:BUILD_ID\log' directory of each job.

Comment: You should have access to the compiler output when the job ends no matter if it runs on a slave or the master.  As for the Jenkins log, there's nothing stopping you from copying it to a location that is accessible on your network.  "Post build tasks" should help with both items.

Comment: It looks like I can use the Groovy Post Build to analyse the build log, so I'll find out how to do this and post something here

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I can get at the build log by using the Groovy Post Build plugin, as follows:

```
def matcher = manager.getLogMatcher(regex);
```

and then use the Regex in Groovy to do analysis